# Creating a custom handler for angularjs http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

Up until now, most of my http requests look something like this.

The controller calls the service followed by a then block

```
ConceptService.save(concept)
.then(function(res){
    if(res.error){ throw new ErrorHandler(res.error)}
    // handle response here
})
```

The ConceptService handles the request like so...

```
// ConceptService.save

function save(vocab){

        var request = {
            url: CONFIG.URL + 'conceptService/save',
            method: 'PUT',
            data: vocab
        }

        return $http(request)
        .then(function(res){
            return res;
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            return err;
        })

    }
```

Sometimes I format the data that comes back from the server in that service

```
// ConceptService.getAllConceptContextType

function getAllConceptContextType(){

        if(ConceptService.conceptContextTypes){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(ConceptService.conceptContextTypes);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        var request = {
            url: CONFIG.URL 'conceptService/getAllConceptContextType' 
            method: 'GET',
        }

        return $http(request)
        .then(function(res){
            var conceptContextTypes = new Object();
            for(var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++){
                conceptContextTypes[res.data[i].id] = res.data[i].type;
            }
            ConceptService.conceptContextTypes = conceptContextTypes;
            return conceptContextTypes;
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            return err;
        })
    }
```

Recently, I've been thinking it might be better to direct these http calls to a central service, and I've been trying code where ConceptService is injected with another service called HttpRequestHandler, which handles the actual request of all calls and returns the response. It looks something like this.

```
// ConceptService.save

function save(vocab){

        var request = {
            url: CONFIG.URL + 'conceptService/save',
            method: 'PUT',
            data: vocab
        }

        return HttpRequestHandler.handle(request)
        .then(function(res){
            //format data here if necessary
            return res;
        })

    }
```

And HttpRequestHandler...

```
// HttpRequestHandler.handle

function handle(request){

        return $http(request)
        .then(function(res){
            return res.data;
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            return err;
        })
    }
```

I guess I just wanted to get any feedback anyone might have about this pattern, problems or potential pitfalls.  I see a couple benefits.  Filters and session data needed for every call can added / modified in one place, and errors will be caught in one place.  The code is a little cleaner, and there are many methods in some of my services.  However, I'm a little concerned that it might affect performance, and there might be other negative aspects of this design that I'm not very aware of.  Any advice or feedback from anyone who has some good experience with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: [`interceptors`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) are already in place for error handling and other operation, What advantage you will get from `HttpRequestHandler.handle`?

Comment: @Satpal Yes, I'm actually using an interceptor already for global error handling. Shouldn't each request implement a catch block anyways, or can I remove the catch block from the service if I'm using an interceptor?

Comment: @Satpal A bit less code if I don't need to rewrite the catch block in every different request, e.g. `return HttpRequestHandler.handle(request)` would be enough if the data didn't need to be formatted before it was returned to the controller.  I suppose managing config sent with every call could be done here, too, even though I'm aware it can also be done in the request block of the interceptor...